# In Emacs24 python mode, how to customize each syntax's color?

Tags: emacs, python-mode

For example, I want "while" to be blue, "for" to be green, how to do that? Beyond colors, can I make syntax bold or italic? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to put the cursor into a string of the given colour and type <kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-face-foreground`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then just confirm the face name and specify the colour. To set the face to bold or italic, use `set-face-font` in a similar way.

You can save the settings into your `.emacs` file:

```
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "gray")
```

This doesn't work in recent Emacs versions when `hl-line-mode` is enabled. You need to get the face name from <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>, as the `set-face-foreground` doesn't auto-complete the face name, but the `hl-line` face.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ALL` of the following keywords are defined within `python.el` as `python-font-lock-keywords`, you would need to trump some of them with a different font face or hack the source for these same keywords to have different font faces:

"and" "del" "from" "not" "while" "as" "elif" "global" "or" "with" "assert" "else" "if" "pass" "yield" "break" "except" "import" "class" "in" "raise" "continue" "finally" "is" "return" "def" "for" "lambda" "try" "print" "exec" "nonlocal" "self".

The following code is an example of how to trump `python-font-lock-keywords` for some of the keywords that have already been defined within `python.el` -- in this example, `while` is blue with **bold**; and, `for` is green with **bold** and *italics*.   `python-font-lock-keywords` that are not trumped by specially defined font faces will default to `font-lock-keyword-face` -- I have included a sample modification of that face as well:

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(font-lock-keyword-face
     ((t (:background "white" :foreground "red" :bold t))))
  )

(defvar lawlist-blue (make-face 'lawlist-blue))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-blue nil
  :background "white" :foreground "blue" :bold t)

(defvar lawlist-green (make-face 'lawlist-green))
(set-face-attribute 'lawlist-green nil
  :background "white" :foreground "green" :bold t :italic t)

(defvar lawlist-keywords-01
  (concat "\\b\\(?:"
    (regexp-opt (list "hello" "world" "while" ))
  "\\)\\b"))

(defvar lawlist-keywords-02
  (concat "\\b\\(?:"
    (regexp-opt (list "foo" "bar" "for" ))
  "\\)\\b"))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode (list

  (list (concat
    "\\("lawlist-keywords-01"\\)") 1 'lawlist-blue t)

  (list (concat
    "\\("lawlist-keywords-02"\\)") 1 'lawlist-green t)

   ))
```

Comment: The code goes inside your `.emacs` file, and then restart the application.  Then, in python-mode, experiment using `while` and experiment using `for` -- you will see that the colors and fonts are what you requested in your initial question above.

Comment: Is it possible to add some keywords into `python-font-lock-keywords` list?

Comment: @alper -- it has been nearly 8 years since I answered the question in this thread, and I've probably learned some new tricks during the passage of time.  Emacs has also undergone revisions during that time.  It would probably be better if you opened a new question over at emacs.stackexchange.com if an answer does not already exist either here or there ...

Comment: Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63317/how-to-color-specific-keywords-in-python-mode // It takes a lot of dedication to stick to something for such a long time, that's awesome

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to make the change permanent

```
M-x customize-face RET font-lock TAB
```

This will give you a list to choose the face that you want to change.
from the buffer that opens it shows you the current variable and you can enter the [ Choose ] link and pick from the color variables of your emacs.