# How do I change a class or module color in ruby mode for emacs 24?

Tags: emacs24, ruby-mode

I want to able to change colors of methods, classes, modules, etc.   I don't know how to do it in an easy way.

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18688387/1030675

Answer (score 0):

Place the point (cursor) on a method, `M-x customize-face` will allow you to change features of the font, just press enter and the Customize Face buffer will pop up. Move the point to **Foreground** and change the colour. `M-<TAB>` will give you a list of available colours. When you have chosen a colour, enter `C-c C-c` and close the buffer. Now you should be done.